# I am stuck with GNU GRUB on my MacOS after removing Ubuntu

Tags: bash, mac, grub-efi

I installed ubuntu 19 on my mac os sometime ago. However, I decided to remove it using gparted after live booting ubuntu using a flash drive. Thereafter, I loaded in MacOS and download the latest "updates" and rebooted... Thereafter, I am stuck with the GNU GRUB screen and am not able to log back into my mac.

I tried restarting with option to see all my boot options... However, I can only see EFI Boot and once I load that, I am always redirected to GNU GRUB. How can I remove gnu grub, or at least load back into mac os without trying to re-install my mac and losing all my value data.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired holding Command-R or Shift-Option-Command-R and booting into recovery mode. Once there you can go into into disk utility and reformat the entire disk delete any existing partitions. Please note this will wipe any and all data on your computer. Then proceed with normal MacOS install.

If you know what are you doing you can remove non macos partition to keep your macos data. Then reboot and see if it boots into MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the start up disk in macOS recovery (command + r) and it had worked for me. You can also try to remove the efi files of ubuntu. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402858/remove-grub-from-macos-catalina but I'm not sure you can access finder on recovery mode.